# extract value between two search patterns on same line

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have the following in a file Output.dat. I need to extract the value between `dn: uid=` and `,ou=`

```
 dn: uid=user1,ou=Active,ou=Member,dc=domain,dc=org
 dn: uid=user2@abc.com,ou=Active,ou=Member,dc=domain,dc=org
 dn: uid=usertest,ou=Active,ou=Member,dc=domain,dc=org
 dn: uid=abc1,ou=Active,ou=Member,dc=domain,dc=org
```

- I tried using

  ```
  sed -e '/dn: uid=/,/,ou=/p' output.dat but
  ```

  it returns complete line instead of value.
- When tried to use

  ```
  sed -e '/dn: uid=/,/,ou=/\1/p' output.dat
  ```

  then got the following error:

  ```
  sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown command: `\'
  ```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a version of GNU grep with PCRE (`-P`) support, then assuming you mean the *first* occurrence of `,ou`

```
grep -oP '(?<=dn: uid=).+?(?=,ou=)' file
```

If you want to match up to the *second* `,ou` you can remove the non-greedy `?` modifier

```
grep -oP '(?<=dn: uid=).+(?=,ou=)' file
```

The expressions in parentheses are zero-length assertions (aka *lookarounds*) meaning that they form part of the match, but are not returned as part of the result. You could do the same thing natively in perl e.g.

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /(?<=dn: uid=)(.+?)(?=,ou=)/' file
```

It's possible to do something *similar* in sed, using regular (non zero-length) grouping e.g. (for GNU sed - other varieties may need additional escaping)

```
sed -rn 's/(.*dn: uid=)([^,]+)(,ou=.*)/\2/p' file
```

or simplifying slightly

```
sed -rn 's/.*dn: uid=([^,]+),ou=.*/\1/p' file
```

Note the `[^,]` is a bit of a hack here, since sed doesn't have a true non-greedy match option.

***Afterthought***: although it's not exactly what you asked, it looks like what you actually want to do is read comma-separated `name=value` pairs from a file, and then further split the value of the first field from its name. You could achieve that in many ways - including

```
awk -F, '{sub(".*=","",$1); print $1}' file
```

*or a pure-bash solution such as*

```
while IFS=, read -r a b c d; do printf '%s\n' "${a#*=}"; done < file
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a good job for awk. You can split the string instead of attempting to use a regex. Here is a solution:

```
$ awk -F= '{ split($2,arr,","); print arr[1]  }' test.txt
user1
user2@abc.com
usertest
abc1
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Is it possible with sed ?

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/[^=]*=\([^,]\+\),.*/\1/' file
```

This assumes the `uid=` will have the first occurrence of `=` on the line and it assumes that you want to stop at the first `,ou=` instance on the line.

**Explanation**

This looks for any number of non `=` characters (`[^=]*`) followed by `=` then matches and saves as many non-commas as it can find ( `\([^,]\+\)` ) followed by a comma and the rest of the line (`,.*`). This means it will replace everything up to and including the first `=` and after the first comma with whatever non-comma characters it finds after the first `=` on the line.

Comment: this didn't work. I am getting the following error  sed 's/=\([^,]\+\),/\1' output.dat
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unterminated `s' command

Comment: @Salton Yes it had a missing `/`. I corrected it and tested it.

Comment: Cool. It works now. It will help if you could please explain this. In your search pattern I don't see "uid" and ",ou"

Comment: @Salton Please see if this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Some more choices, in order of length:

1. GNU `grep` with PCREs

   ```
   grep -oP 'uid=\K[^,]+' file
   ```

   The `\K` discards everything matched up to that point, which combined with the `-o` switch will cause `grep` to print only the longest stretch of non `,` characters  that comes after the `uid=`.
2. `awk`

   ```
   awk -F'[=,]' '{print $2}' file
   ```

   `-F'[=,]` sets the field separator to be either `=` or `,` so the 2nd field is the user name.
3. `sed`

   ```
   sed -r 's/.{8}([^,]*).*/\1/' file
   ```

   That will match the first 7 characters (`.{7}`) `=`, capture the longest stretch of non-`,` as `\1` and replace the whole line with `\1`.
4. `perl`

   ```
   perl -pe 's/.+?=([^,]+).*/$1/' file
   ```

   The `-pe` means "print  every line after applying the script given by -e". The `s///` is the substitution operator and the regular expression looks for the 1st (`.+?`, the `?` makes it match the shortest possible string) `=` and then captures the longest stretch of non-`,` characters after that. The `s///` replaces what was matched with what was captured (what was inside the parentheses).
5. `cut`

   ```
   cut -d'=' -f 2 file | cut -d ',' -f 1
   ```

   The `-d` sets the delimiter to `=` so the 2nd (`-f 2`) field is `username,ou`. The second `cut` uses `,` as delimiter and prints the username alone.