# Grep for a number excluding its floating point part

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have this following line

```
scalar TestDmaMac4.sink.udpApp[0]   throughput:last     11730.559888477
```

I want to extract only `11730` out of this line, how can I do it with `grep`? I want to ignore the number after decimal point and only need digits before decimal point.

*(Note: there is a* {space}{tab} *sequence separating each of `udpApp[0]`, `throughput:last` and the number beginning `11730`.)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extract value between two search patterns on same line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131399/extract-value-between-two-search-patterns-on-same-line)

Comment: @Sundeep No, i only want the number ignoring the numbers after the floating point

Comment: yes, and it is possible using look-arounds if `-P` is available as shown in accepted answer in that question... or using sed/awk etc... do add the command you tried but failed... we can help you correct it

Comment: Does it need to be a regex at all? can't you use something like `awk '{print int($NF)}'`

Comment: Is the number always complete up to the decimal? e.g. then `egrep -o '[0-9]+\.' | tr -d .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bellow regexp will match any floating number in the format `[0-9].[0-9]` and will return the integer part of this floating number.

```
$ a="scalar TestDmaMac4.sink.udpApp[0] throughput:last 11730.559888477"
$ egrep -o '[0-9]+[.][0-9]' <<<"$a" |egrep -o '[0-9]+[^.]'  #First grep will isolate the floating number , second grep will isolate the int part.
11730
$ perl -pe 's/(.*?)([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+.*)/\2/' <<<"$a"  #using the lazy operator ?
11730
$ sed -r 's/(.*[^0-9.])([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+.*)/\2/' <<<"$a"  #sed does not have lazy operator thus we simulate this with negation
11730
```

For the sake of testing, i also tried above regexp in a different string with floatting number at different position without a leading space:

```
$ c="scalar throughput:last11730.559888477 TestDmaMac4.sink.udpApp[0]"
$ egrep -o '[0-9]+[.][0-9]' <<<"$c" |egrep -o '[0-9]+[^.]'
11730
$ perl -pe 's/(.*?)([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+.*)/\2/' <<<"$c"
11730
$ sed -r 's/(.*[^0-9.])([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+.*)/\2/' <<<"$c"
11730
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l='scalar TestDmaMac4.sink.udpApp[0]   throughput:last     11730.559888477'
read -r -a a <<<"$l"
dc -e "${a[-1]}dX10r^dsa*la/p"

echo "$l" | perl -lane 'print/\d+(?=\.\d+$)/g'
```

## result

```
11730
```

Answer (score -2):

**Using Grep:**

```
grep -o " [0-9]\{1,\}"
```

**To Test:**

```
echo "scalar TestDmaMac4.sink.udpApp[0] throughput:last 11730.559888477" | grep -o " [0-9]\{1,\}"
```

**results:**

```
11730
```